# 最大値を取る時の組み合わせ

Tags: r

下の問題を解きたいのですがうまく行きません。
Rでexpand.gridを使いましたがメモリオーバーしました。

Q, max(performance1+performance2)

ただし num1+num2<=1000

data1.txtとdata2.txtで両者ともタブ区切りのファイルです。
変数は3つ以上ありますが簡単のため省略しました。
とりあえずパフォーマンスが最大になる時（制約を満たして）の組み合わせだけでも取得できたらと思っています。
できたらパフォーマンス最大の時の列の取得、もしくはそれぞれの行の取得もしたいです。

```
        performance1  num1  hoge1
1                 12    15   3.2
2                 11  12.1   2.4

        performance2 num2   hoge2
1               25.3   14     2.6
2                 21 18.3     4.1
```

あまりメモリを食わない方法でお願いします。
dplyrなどパッケージは好きなものを使って構わないです。
よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`expand.grid()` の代わりに単純ループを使ってみました。

```
data1 <- read.table("data1.txt", sep="\t", header=T)
data2 <- read.table("data2.txt", sep="\t", header=T)
pf <- -Inf
max <- list()
for(i in seq(nrow(data1))){
  for(j in seq(nrow(data2))){
    if (data1[i,"num1"] + data2[j,"num2"] <= 1000) {
      d1 <- data1[i,"performance1"]
      d2 <- data2[j,"performance2"]
      if ((d1+d2) > pf) {
        pf <- (d1+d2)
        max <- list(c(i, j), c(d1, d2))
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`max` に `performance` の和が最大になる場合の行番号と値の組み合わせが格納されます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。特殊な函数など使わなくてもここまでかけるんですね。参考にさせていただきます。